# use isolation level snapshot entity framework 4

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, webforms, sql-server-2012

I'm try to using a TransactionScope with isolation level snapshot on Entity framework 4 in asp.net web proyect and sql server 2012 standard edition. I'm getting this error `Transactions with IsolationLevel Snapshot cannot be promoted.`

```
     using (var scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew, 
                new TransactionOptions { IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.Snapshot })) { 

                    using (var db = new Datos.TestDBDataContext(System.Configuration
    .ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ApplicationServices"].ConnectionString))
                            {                   
                                Datos.Contacto newUser = new Datos.Contacto
                                {
                                    name = user.name,
                                    lastName = user.lastName,
                                    type = user.type,
                                    userId = user.userId,
                                    email = user.Email,
                                    password = Password(),
                                    jobCode = user.JobCode,                                
                                    DateCreated = user.DateCreated,
                                    cityCode = user.cityCode,
                                    numberPass = user.numberPass,
                                    place = user.place,
                                    estate = false
                                };

                                db.Contacts.InsertOnSubmit(newUser);
                                db.SubmitChanges();                
                        }
                        scope.Complete();
   }
```

What I'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Please try as shown below.Set the `IsolationLevel.Serializable`.

> Serializable :     Volatile data can be read but not modified, and no new
>   data can be added during the transaction.

[**IsolationLevel Enumeration**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.isolationlevel(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
var scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew, 
   new TransactionOptions { 
         IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.Snapshot, 
         IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.Serializable,
})
```

Comment: Can you explain more your answer, what serializable does in this case ?

Comment: I can't add a duplicate IsolationLevel, Visual studio error " Duplicate initialitaon of IsolationLevel"